# Sql Server query varchar data sort like int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have one table like

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
P_Id int,
amount varchar(50)
)
```

Data Like

```
Id amount
----------
1 2340
2 4568
3 10000
```

Now I want to sort table by amount but one problem is amount is varchar so it sort table like this

```
Id amount
----------
3 10000
1 2340
2 4568
```

but i want result like this

```
Id amount
----------
3 10000
2 4568
1 2340
```

what should i do ?

Comment: why do you want to store amount as VARCHAR ?

Comment: Indeed, why not make it a numeric type?

Comment: You have a design flaw in your database. You should use the correct datatype for the data. The earlier you fix this the less effort you will have to make afterwards to get around it.

Comment: You can use cast or convert in your order by clause but better to change the data type

Comment: It is mistake but now i can't change table design so. . i work with varchar only.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Cast amount column into Numeric in `ORDER BY` clause while selecting:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY CAST(amount AS Numeric(10,0)) DESC
```

You can change the decimal point value according to your requirement to get more precise result:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY CAST(amount AS Numeric(10,2)) DESC
                                   ^
```

Result:

| Id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 10000 |
| 2 | 4568 |
| 1 | 2340 |

See [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=01f9f8fd40c834a50baed70edd10dfd9)

**Note**: As @Ice suggested, this will fail if the amount field contains non numeric data like `ab123` or `xyz` (obviously).

Comment: Be carefull, statement will fail if Amount cannot be converted to a numeric value. This will also happen with nice values like 10.5 or 10,5 depending on some country configurations.

Comment: @Ice: That's obvious. If the amount field values like `ab123` or `xyz` it will fail and there is no point of ordering in that case. Reg. decimal values, we can add decimal points according to our requirement. E.g. `AS Numeric(10,2)` instead of `AS Numeric(10,0)`.

Answer (score 17):

Try ABS():

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ABS(MyCol) DESC;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae482/3)**

Comment: This worked, the chosen answer did not.  Could this be a version issue?
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax...near 'Numeric(10,0)) desc limit 10' at line 1`

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue or sorting varchar as number (INT)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`SELECT *
FROM #varchar_field
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(mixed_field) = 1 THEN CAST(mixed_field AS FLOAT)
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(mixed_field,1)) = 0 THEN ASCII(LEFT(LOWER(mixed_field),1)) 
        ELSE 2147483647
    END`

Ref: http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/how-to-order-numeric-values-in-a-varchar-field