# Order from MySQL order

Tags: php, mysql

This is MySQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT users.*, ranks.rank_number
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN ranks
        ON users.rank_name=ranks.rank_name
        WHERE users.active= 'y'
        ORDER BY ranks.rank_number ASC, users.plvl DESC
        LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

I want to order by `rank_number` as:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

from MySQL, but I get this:

```
1,11,12,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

So how can I make it as `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`?

Comment: remove `users.plvl DESC` from your `ORDER BY` clause. You're combining 2 order by parameters

Comment: Write information about the columns types of your tables.

Comment: Your field type needs to be some kind of int. It seems to be a char/varchar.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Yes they are varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest fix to your statement is to append **`+0`** to `ranks.rank_number` in the `ORDER BY` clause...

```
ORDER BY ranks.rank_number+0 ASC, ...
                          ^^
```

That will "work" if `rank_number` is `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` datatype, and you want to sort by the *numeric* value, rather than sorting the string representation.

There are other expressions that achieve an equivalent result, converting the string representation into a numeric value. The "add zero" trick is the shortest fix, just a two character addition to the statement.

Normally, we tend to store *numeric* values in columns declared with numeric datatypes (integer, decimal, float), rather than storing them as strings. Then we avoid the kind of issue you are reporting with ordering.

---

The order you show the rows being returned in is very odd.

Are you *positive* that **`10`** is being ordered after **`12`**? If this was being sorted/ordered as string values, we'd expect the string value **`10`** to come before **`11`**. The order that you report the rows being returned in is just very odd.

(If the order you report the rows being returned in is accurate, then I suspect that second character is actually capital O **`'O'`** rather than a zero **`'0'`**.

If that's the case, then the `+0` trick will convert **`'1O'+0`** (one and capital O) into a numeric value of **`1`**, so that would be equivalent to **`'1'+0`**, which will also evaluates to **`1`**.

Comment: ORDER BY ranks.rank_number+0, this function perfect, now it sorts right

Answer (score 2):

Basedon your results it looks like you are getting alphabetic sorting. it looks like in your database, the rank_number is likely stored as "varchar" instead of integer. in that case, you can cast the varchar to an integer to get numeric sorting instead of alphabetic sorting.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

```
SELECT users.*, CAST (ranks.rank_number AS SIGNED) as user_rank 
...
order by user_rank ASC
```

Posting your table definitions will help clarify if this is actually the case..

Answer (score 1):

Convert it into int

`ORDER BY CAST(ranks.rank_number AS Numeric(10,0)) ASC`

From [Sql Server query varchar data sort like int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829663/sql-server-query-varchar-data-sort-like-int)

Comment: ok, i will converted to ORDER BY CAST(ranks.rank_number AS Numeric(10,0)) ASC thanks for help all...